# hibernate doesn't update discriminator column when I update with another object

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have used a "class per hierarchy strategy" for mapping the following class hierarchy in Hibernate.

I have **Item** as an abstract class.
The followings as concrete ones:
**Book** 
**Journal** 
**DVD** 
**CD**

My mapping works perfect for saving and loading but it doesn't work correctly on updating an item with a different class.
I'm using discriminators for each of the above classes.

my item.hbm.xml is like:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="my.hibernate.items.Item" discriminator-value="item"
        table="testitem" catalog="efeu">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="item_type" type="string" length="8" />
        <subclass name="my.hibernate.items.DVD" discriminator-value="DVD">
            <property name="duration" type="java.lang.Integer" column="duration" />
            <property name="trackNumber" type="java.lang.Integer"
                column="trackNumber" />
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="my.hibernate.items.Journal"
            discriminator-value="Journal">
            <property name="serialNumber" type="java.lang.Integer"
                column="serial_number" />
        </subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and for updating I use this method:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
public static void updateItem(Item newItem){
    Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    session.update(newItem);// I tried merge too. it created a new row

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

There is no difference which class instance I send to updateItem method. All the fields are updated except the discriminator so if it is a book remains a book and I can't convert it to CD, DVD or journal invoking the above method with an object of that kind as parameter.

I think it is clear what I am doing. I assum that I know that the row with id=111 in the database table is a Book object. So I do the following:

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
Item cd = new CD();
cd.setId(111);
cd.setXXXProperties()
Item.updateItem(cd);
```

it is clear that cd is transient before invoking the method and I haven't loaded the row with id=111 before that.

What should I do to make Hibernate change the discriminator column on invoking the update method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way how to update a `discriminator` value. What you are experiencing is correct. Once object is created (as a CD or as a Book) it won't change its type.

Read more here: [5.1.6.1.1. Discriminator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-discriminator)

```
<discriminator
        column="discriminator_column"                      (1)
        type="discriminator_type"                          (2)
        force="true|false"                                 (3)
        insert="true|false"                                (4)
        formula="arbitrary sql expression"                 (5)
/>
```

There is no update operation for discriminator.

Comment: No! It causes me a huge problem! Do you mean that for updating the item elements I should delete the row and insert it again? In that case, I will have to change the id assignment strategy and set it manually to avoid changing the id on every update!

Comment: Take it form other way. If there are other entities referencing the *Book* (e.g. `Reader`) with ID 111, and Hibernate would allow to change it to *CD*? Now there will be `Reader` referencing *CD*? iIt could cause DB foreign key issues. But mostly, it will break the domain logic. Not only you have to delete the row and insert new one, but it must(ok, at least should) have new ID!

Comment: @Johnny, you could use a native update like: `UPDATE items SET item_type = :type and item_id = :id`